# How to insert string or newline before a pattern "Using SED" ( Without replacing the pattern) In MAC OS

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I have a file with the following content:

```
aaaabbaaabbaa
```

and i need an output like:

```
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
```

I need a new line to be added before first occurrence of `'b'`. I need only SED command to use in bash

I am using the following command. I know its now the perfect one..

Can anyone tell me a better command than this. 
Pl note only SED command i need to use in bash

```
sed -i.bak  -e 's/bb/qbb/g' input.txt  
sed -i.bak  -e 's/qbb/\'$'\nbb/g' input.txt
```

Comment: Skip the `q` intermediary and just use `'s/b/\'$'\n'bb/g`.

Comment: Shortest: **11** chars: `s/b+/\n&/g` + `r` switch: `sed -re 's/b+/\n&/g'` will do the job.

Answer (score 11):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo "aaaabbaaabbaa" | sed -r 's/([b]+)/\n\1/g'
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
```

`sed -r` allows to catch blocks with `()` and print them back with `\1`. The block it catches it `[b]+`, meaning `"one or more b's"`, and prints it back preceded by a new line.

As I see you are using `sed -i`, it is also good to do:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/([b]+)/\n\1/g' input.txt
```

---

Also, easier ([thanks Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589970/how-to-insert-string-or-newline-before-a-pattern-using-sed-without-replacing#comment29075498_19590054)!)

```
$ echo "aaaabbaaabbaa" | sed 's/b\+/\n&/g'
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
```

It replaces all sequences of "b" and replaces that with a newline followed by that same sequence of "b" (`&` represents whatever was matched on the left side of `s///`).

Comment: Don't strictly need `-r` for this: `sed 's/b\+/\n&/g'`

Comment: Uhms, so this is good news: when catching just one block we can play with `&`, no need to `\1`. I like it, thanks! Updated, also.

Comment: There is extra `1` appearing after `bb` in output because of `&1`.

Comment: Oooops I was doing some tests and forgot to delete it :) Thanks @anubhava!

Comment: Don't bother with `+`, just `sed 's/b/\nb/g'` is fine. Those with `sed`s that don't take escapes like that, the `\n` will have to be a backslash (``\``) followed by a literal newline.

Comment: @sam indicate what error you are receiving, which one of the solutions in my question you tried...

Comment: when i use sed -r 's/([b]+)/\n\1/g' input.txt
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: @sam then you can use either `sed 's/\([b]+\)/\n\1/g` or `sed 's/b\+/\n&/g'`

Comment: @sam What do you mean no change? Be more explicit if you want to be helped. I guess you are getting the result in the screen, right? If you read my answer, adding `-i` updated the file.

Comment: @fedorqui  even i tried -i I couldn't see any change in the file...No change means no change in file text..

Comment: What if you do not use `-i`? Do you see change in the output? In that case, you can do `sed .... file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file`

Comment: @fedorqui
$ sed  's/\([b]+\)/\n\1/g' input.txt > tmp.txt
$ sed 's/b\+/\n&/g' input.txt > tmp.txt   

no change between input and tmp files...
$ sed -i 's/b\+/\n&/g' input.txt > tmp.txt 
and for '-i'
sed: 1: "input.txt": command i expects \ followed by text
thank you for your patience

Comment: @sam as you are on Mac OS and I don't have it to test, you'd better check the other answers.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui kindly up vote it if you feels its a good question..
and none of the answers right... for SED command for this requirement..

Answer (score 3):

`grep -oP` with lookahead regex will be easier:

```
echo 'aaaabbaaabbaa' | grep -oP '.+?[^b](?=(b|$))'

aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
```

Comment: Fine for `grep`s with `-P`, but OSX took that out in 10.8.

Comment: So your grepv doesn't support  grep -P ?

Answer (score 2):

If your input string really does contain only `a` and `b` characters, then I think the problem degenerates to a simple replacement of all instances of `ab` with `a<newline>b`.  If this is the case then you can omit `sed` altogether and use the [Shell Parameter Expansion feature in bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions):

At the terminal:

```
$ str="aaaabbaaabbaa"
$ echo "${str//ab/a
> b}"
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
$
```

Or in a shell script:

```
$ cat ab.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "${1//ab/a
b}"
$ ./ab.sh "aaaabbaaabbaa"
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
$
```

This works for me on OSX 10.8.5.

This information is also available on the [bash manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html) hosted by apple.com.  Search for "parameter/pattern" on that page.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly `awk` version :)

```
echo "aaaabbaaabbaa" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf ($i=="b" && f!="b" ?"\n":"")"%s",$i; f=$i}} END {print ""}' FS=
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
```

---

A `gnu awk` version

```
echo "aaaabbaaabbaa" | awk '{$1=$1} NR>1 {$0=RS $0;} 1' RS="bb"
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
```

---

Another `awk`. Replace any `b` or group of `b` with newline and itself `&`

```
echo "aaaabbaaabbaa" | awk 'gsub(/b+/,"\n&")'
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
```

Comment: I do see.  But if `awk` is installed (its normal installed) and do a better job, you may have a better tool for you.

Comment: i don't want the users to install awk for me..  thats why no AWK

Comment: Added another `awk` version.  What system are you on that does not have `awk`?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "aaaabbaaabbaa\nbbaabba" | sed 's/\([^b]\)b/\1\
b/g'

aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
bbaa
bba
```

posix compliant and does not make a new line if line start with a b

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed -e :a -e '/ab\(.*\)\(.\)$/!b' -e G -e 's//a\2b\1/' -e ta file
```

This loops through the current line replacing any `ab` combinations with `a\nb`. It uses the hold space side-effect that a newline is always present when a new instance of sed is created.

Of course:

```
sed 's/bb*/\n&/g' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/bb*/'"\n"'&/g' file
```

Is a lot easier but probably depends on a GNU version of sed or bash.

Answer (score 1):

sed  -e 's/bb/\
nn/g' input.txt

I got this to work. It is very similar to your original attempt. I am on an iMac, so I am pretty sure the same will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you want avoid new line when `b` occurs at beginning of line and all of this POSIX compliant.

```
$ echo -e "aaaabbaaabbaa\nbbaaaabbaaabbaa" | sed -e 's/\([^b]\)b/\1\nb/g'
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
bbaaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
```

Comment: it works fine in terminal... but when i insert it in my bash script its  not working...

Comment: @sam: It sound strange. Your terminal is running shell. What you type in terminal is (should be) exactly same as line in shell script. If doesn't, something is really broken.

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

```
$ echo aaaabbaaabbaa | sed 's/b\{1,\}/\'$'\n&/g'
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
```

or

```
$ echo aaaabbaaabbaa | sed $'s/b\{1,\}/\\\n&/g'
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
```

---

In order to make `sed` interpret the regex as extended regular expressions, you could use the `-E` option:

```
$ echo aaaabbaaabbaa | sed -E 's/b+/\'$'\n&/g'
aaaa
bbaaa
bbaa
```